# sharepoint provider hosted app in visual studio 2017 to publish on organization level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I need to create sharepoint Add-in and publish it to organisation app catalogue with ruby on rails. Below are the steps I have followed,

1. Created developer site with developer site template
2. Created an app in visual studio and deployed it on site.
3. while creating sharepoint add-in, had configured redirect url as my already created rails app and permission added of `siteCollection` as read in `Appmanifest.xml`

I am trying to get site contents and files and documents but only getting metadata info have tried below REST urls

```
https://{site_url}/sites/{developer_site_name}/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents')/Files
```

I have uploaded 2 files on the site but not getting in the API result. Please help, where I am wrong and how can I get the documents/ site content.

Answer (score 0):

You could use below rest api to get file content.

```
/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/MyDoc/toc.docx')/openbinarystream
```